# Was this feature available in previous .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, delegates, callback, dependency-properties

I am looking at some code from [Charles Petzold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337899.aspx), he is using the following syntax for `PropertyChangedCallback`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty =
  EllipseGeometry.CenterProperty.AddOwner(
    typeof(CenteredEllipse),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0), 
      EllipsePropertyChanged));
```

It doesn't work if you do it this way you need put the property changed callback in new `new PropertyChangedCallback(EllipsePropertyChanged)`. He is also editing the variables directly:

```
 void EllipsePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  elipGeo.Center = Center;
  elipGeo.RadiusX = RadiusX;
  elipGeo.RadiusY = RadiusY;
  InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

Should it be something like this:

```
static void EllipsePropertyChnaged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        EllipseGoemetry ellipseGeo = (EllipseGoemetry )obj;
        args.newValue ...
    }
```

Does someone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is an example of Delegate Type Inference.  From this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2008/09/23/delegate-type-inference-in-c.aspx

> What I didn't know until today is that line #13 would work, that you
>   can just pass the method name as the parameter and the delegate type
>   would be inferred.  Nice and easy.  Line #14/#15 was also new to me,
>   well at least the part about using () for an empty parameter list.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, it doesn't recognize the name and any filed of the class. I had to cast obj into the class and then modify the variables.

Answer (score 1):

`elipGeo` is defined as a field of the class, that code is correct.

You do not need to explicity create delegates from methods, that is done implicitly, [this feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) was added in C# 2.0.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, it doesn't recognize the name and any filed of the class. I had to cast obj into the class and then modify the variables.

Comment: @mihajlv: I am not going to test that code, did you even copy everything 1:1?

Comment: I'll give it another shot. Thanks.

Comment: I figured what was going on, I posted it as an answer. Thanks for the explanation though.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that he uses the same names for two method so it can get confusing:

```
static void EllipsePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj,
  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  (obj as CenteredEllipse).EllipsePropertyChanged(args);
}
```

---

```
void EllipsePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  elipGeo.Center = Center;
  elipGeo.RadiusX = RadiusX;
  elipGeo.RadiusY = RadiusY;
  InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

The first one is the delegate, the second one is just a method of the class, which he is calling in the delegate, where he casts obj, just as it supposed to be done.